# Could not create Xamarin.Forms application

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, compiler-errors, driver, xamarin.forms

I create a blank Xamarin.Forms application
but I have some errors.

I get these 2 errors when Cross-Platform projects are loading:
[image]

**Update :** I have found the reason of this 1st error:
I didn't have been set the application and package name on the Android Manifest page.

[image]

And get this error on debug and cannot debug:
[image]

What could be the reasons of these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 clearly tells you that you are missing a Visual Studio update.  Have you tried downloading the update like it suggests?

3 is because you are trying to execute a Library project, which is not allowed.  You need to right click on your Droid project in Solution Explorer, and choose "Set as Startup Project".  This will cause your Droid project to run by default.